# Cannot connect to remote MySQL with VB6 (10060)

Tags: mysql, vb6, remote-access

I got a hosting plan from GKG.net and I have a VB6 connection string to remotely reach MySQL database in it. I followed all instructions and tutorials about how to reach MySQL server remotely. Everything was fine till i get an error that says:

> [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (10060)

I searched for a solution over the net for hours but still there is nothing makes sense about it.. I double checked my connections.. I can ping to my static ip, but cant reach the MySQL server in it.

From CPanel i can reach my db with phpMyAdmin. I tested my db and there was nothing wrong with it. Everything seems right. Except i still get the error message with VB6

My connection string:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim constr As String
Private Sub OpenServer()
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    constr = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" & _
             "PORT=" & db_port & ";" & _
             "SERVER=" & db_server & ";" & _
             "DATABASE=" & db_name & ";" & _
             "UID=" & db_user & ";" & _
             "PWD=" & db_pass & ";" & _
             "OPTION=3;" & _
             "STMT=;"
    conn.Open constr
End Sub
```

So how can i resolve this damned connection issue? and 
What are the odds that causes this?

Comment: It quite clearly says that it can't connect. Either the details are wrong or the server is not accessible from the internet. There is nothign your client code can do about it.

Comment: @Deanna lol i didnt ask as whats wrong with my code. I just showed it for people who asks "Whats your connection string? You sure it works?" Anyway thanks for mentioning that my code cant do a thing and seems like i should have a fight with my provider to double check my server's remote access. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hosts where you access their database server very rarely allow remote access to the database from outside their hosting environment (I have never seen it).

If you setup the MySql database yourself (on a dedicated or virtual server plan) then you should be able to set it up to accept remote hosts.  In that case you need to modify your my.con file to allow remote hosts (you can also do it via the MySql Admin tools) and you need to grant the login you are trying to use access from the remote IP:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Your previous comment about SQLyog is a very good idea.  And I can vouch for that product.  It is a great tool.  The free admin tools from MySql (Workbench - http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) are also decent and will allow you to test remote access as well.

Answer (score 4):

check this Solution to Connecting remotely when you get Error 10060

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?34,49742,239961

http://www.bigresource.com/VB-Remote-MySQL-Server-h6Z8Cbaszz.html#

MySQL is setup to handle remote connections very easily. However, you must setup MySQL to allow your users in. The other thing to do, is make sure port 3306 is open on the host. If it is not, then you can't connect to MySQL. The easiest way to do this is to...

telnet myhost 3306

If you get something back like...
,
3.23.54-log▬I_&:309i☻

then port 3306 is open and MySQL is listening.

Next, make sure your userid is setup to allow access on the MySQL server. You can do this with the mysql client software, or the mysqlcc software.

Hope this helps

Comment: i already passed trough the links you gave. Doesnt solved anything. Port 3306 open for both TCP and UDP. I can ping my static ip yet cant connect to MySQL. Reason of 10060 error is not obvious thats why im crushing walls. Also if you can find i need spesific info about how my hosting provider handles this issue. Thanks for your answer i'll try SQLyog as a mysqlcc soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I could connect from localhost but not from a client computer. I turned off Windows firewall (windows 8). However, no joy. I then created a new rule in firewall advanced settings and BINGO it worked. The new rule just allowed incoming connections on port 3306 on my private network.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach for VB6. I use it like this in all my apps and its been working for years.

> Dim StoreDB As ADODB.Connection
>
> On Error Resume Next
>
> Set StoreDB = New ADODB.Connection
>
> StoreDB.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=000.000.000.000;Port=3306;Database=yourDBName;User=Someusername;Password=Somepassword;OPTION=8;"
>
> > If Err.Number = 0 Then
> >
> > > [VB6 Code to execute]
> > >
> > > Else
> > >
> > > myErrorString = Err.Description
> >
> > End If
>
> StoreDB.Close
>
> Set StoreDB = Nothing

As mentioned, ensure port is 3306. I have a host that uses 3307. I see no problem with your code. You probably need to sort this with the host.

Answer (score -1):

Add mysqlid.exe into your windows firewall settings to access your server remotely