# 2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.xxx' (10060)

Tags: python, mysql, network-programming, centos, mariadb

I just installed new CentOS operating system on server and restored all the databases. 
i was trying to fetch the data remotely from Windows using Python script.
It returned me with this error

```
PS C:\Python27\practice> python .\server_test_script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\server_test_script.py", line 9, in <module>
db="transactions") # name of the data base
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 193, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on   '192.168.1.XXX' (10060)")
```

i have already changed my /etc/my.cnf file with bind-address=0.0.0.0. and one thing more it installed mariadb server this time when i downloaded mysql using yum command. Is that the issue but i dont think as  both provide the same service using same packages .I have already created myself as a user with all the privileges but still it didnt work.

Here is my Python script

```
import MySQLdb 
con = MySQLdb.connect(host="192.168.1.xxx", # your host, usually localhost
user="shubham", # your username
passwd="xxxxx", # your password
db="transactions") # name of the data base
cur = con.cursor()
def getTransactioncount():
    cur.execute("select count(tid) from transaction")
    row=cur.fetchall()
    count=row[0][0]
    return count

print getTransactioncount()
```

Can anyone please help me to find where i am doing wrong
Thanks

Comment: Are you certain the MySQL server is actually running on your centos system, that it is listening on the standard port (as you haven't specified a port in your client code I assume it uses the default port (3306?) Are you certain there isn't a firewall blocking the network connection to your server from your client? Your problem looks like a basic server-not-running-on-expected-port or server-not-contactable sort of problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just checked, its running on the default port 3306 and i also tried running the script after turning off the firewall on the client PC but no still luck.

Comment: What about the firewall in CentOs, is that letting 3306 through? Can you run the script locally on the server successfully? From the client, can you telnet (using putty, maybe?) to the server port 3306 - just connecting would confirm that the network path is clear.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

Comment: SO finally worked, just after trying disabling the firewall on client , i tried turning off firewall on server and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the network connection from your client to your server - most likely that is the problem. Also see [Cannot connect to remote MySQL with VB6 (10060)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349948/cannot-connect-to-remote-mysql-with-vb6-10060) and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html